# Android : basic test with espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I'm trying to add a basic espresso test in my android application. My test file (located in androidTest/java folder) was generated by the 'record espresso test' feature and is as below :

```
package info.my_xxxx.activities;


import android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import info.my_xxxx.R;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;

@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class AdviceDisplay2 {

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<SplashActivity> mActivityTestRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(SplashActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void adviceDisplay2() {
        // Added a sleep statement to match the app's execution delay.
        // The recommended way to handle such scenarios is to use Espresso idling resources:
        // https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/index.html
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ViewInteraction appCompatImageView = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.third_button),
                        childAtPosition(
                                allOf(withId(R.id.linear_layout),
                                        childAtPosition(
                                                withId(R.id.bottom_button),
                                                0)),
                                2),
                        isDisplayed()));
        appCompatImageView.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction textView = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.advice),
                        childAtPosition(
                                allOf(withId(R.id.RelativeLayout01),
                                        childAtPosition(
                                                withId(android.R.id.content),
                                                0)),
                                1),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textView.check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    }

    private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's just about clicking on a view and checking if a view is existing or not... My gradle file (module level) is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

    }

    signingConfigs{
        release {
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation ('com.squareup:android-times-square:1.7.2@aar'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'mediarouter-v7'
    }

    implementation files('libs/GraphView-3.1.3.jar')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Kotlin related
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // Required for local unit tests (JUnit 4 framework)
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    // Required for instrumented tests
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

}
```

All the dependencies seems to be ok but when running the test from android studio, I got this message after few minutes :

> android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 2969
>   iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed . at
>   dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1536) at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:90)
>   at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
>   at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
>   at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:167)
>   at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:110)
>   at
>   info.xxx.activities.AdviceDisplay2.adviceDisplay2(AdviceDisplay2.java:56)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   at
>   android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
>   at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)
>
> Tests ran to completion.

Line 56 is :

`appCompatImageView.perform(click());`

Thank you for reading

Comment: How you integrate Espresso in your project . I used its dependence like you but it didn't define .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today, but in my case, it was related to the libs versioning. I wasted a long time trying to figure out how to get my tests back passing, and one of the key for figuring my problem out was by setting the `buildToolsVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` and `support-annotations lib` to the same version.

So, please could you try to update your `buildToolsVersion '25.2.0'` and check if it works?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if I change the buildToolsVersion, it returns the message : Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

Comment: I see... What about change the others to sdk version 26 and the support-annotation to `26.0.2`? (Maybe you'll need to update some others dependencies)

Comment: I've updated sdk and dependencies to 26 (see my gradle file updated in message) but the same error is still here....